# SFML ошибка при билде

Tags: sfml, rust, build-error

```
[sfml 0.20.0] running: "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-Z7" "-Brepro" "-I" "CSFML/src/" "-I" "C:\\libs\\x64\\SFML\\include" "-W4" "-DCSFML_SYSTEM_EXPORTS" "-DCSFML_AUDIO_EXPORTS" "-DCSFML_WINDOW_EXPORTS" "-DCSFML_GRAPHICS_EXPORTS" "-FoC:\\Users\\pon\\source\\repos\\Rust_3D\\target\\debug\\build\\sfml-7a4b2763bdb60f0c\\out\\CSFML/src/Window/Touch.o" "-c" "CSFML/src/Window/Touch.cpp"
[sfml 0.20.0] Touch.cpp
[sfml 0.20.0] CSFML/src/Window/Touch.cpp(13): error C2039: "Window": �� ���� 童��� "sf".
[sfml 0.20.0] C:\libs\x64\SFML\include\SFML/Window/Touch.hpp(35): note:  �. ������� "sf"
[sfml 0.20.0] CSFML/src/Window/Touch.cpp(13): error C4430: ��������� ᯥ�䨪��� ⨯� - �।���������� int. �ਬ�砭��. C++ �� �����ন���� int �� 㬮�砭��
[sfml 0.20.0] CSFML/src/Window/Touch.cpp(13): error C2143: ᨭ⠪��᪠� �訡��: ������⢨� "," ��। "*"
[sfml 0.20.0] CSFML/src/Window/Touch.cpp(14): error C2065: relativeTo: ��������� �����䨪���
[sfml 0.20.0] exit code: 2
[sfml 0.20.0]
[sfml 0.20.0]
[sfml 0.20.0] error occurred: Command "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-Z7" "-Brepro" "-I" "CSFML/src/" "-I" "C:\\libs\\x64\\SFML\\include" "-W4" "-DCSFML_SYSTEM_EXPORTS" "-DCSFML_AUDIO_EXPORTS" "-DCSFML_WINDOW_EXPORTS" "-DCSFML_GRAPHICS_EXPORTS" "-FoC:\\Users\\pon\\source\\repos\\Rust_3D\\target\\debug\\build\\sfml-7a4b2763bdb60f0c\\out\\CSFML/src/Window/Touch.o" "-c" "CSFML/src/Window/Touch.cpp" with args "cl.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 2).
[sfml 0.20.0]
[sfml 0.20.0]
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: Custom SFML include dir: C:\libs\x64\SFML\include

error: failed to run custom build command for `sfml v0.20.0`

Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\pon\source\repos\Rust_3D\target\debug\build\sfml-86d9ae075e643885\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
--- stderr


error occurred: Command "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-Z7" "-Brepro" "-I" "CSFML/src/" "-I" "C:\\libs\\x64\\SFML\\include" "-W4" "-DCSFML_SYSTEM_EXPORTS" "-DCSFML_AUDIO_EXPORTS" "-DCSFML_WINDOW_EXPORTS" "-DCSFML_GRAPHICS_EXPORTS" "-FoC:\\Users\\pon\\source\\repos\\Rust_3D\\target\\debug\\build\\sfml-7a4b2763bdb60f0c\\out\\CSFML/src/Window/Touch.o" "-c" "CSFML/src/Window/Touch.cpp" with args "cl.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 2).
```

Comment: надеюсь что кто нибудь ответит)

Comment: А какие переменные окружения добавляли? Похоже `SFML_INCLUDE_DIR` добавили, а `SFML_LIBS_DIR` нет.

Comment: @vessd Я добавил, странно

Comment: Попробуйте более новую версию напрямую с гита https://github.com/jeremyletang/rust-sfml

Comment: Там самая новая версия, видно же

Comment: И почему вообще в ошибке китайские символы

Comment: @SuperViktor123Hah 0.20.0 это НЕ самая новая версия, на гите лежит новее, попробуйте с гита

Comment: ¿Почему в тегах стоит rust а не С++? ¿Откуда этот лог сборки? ¿Почему там крякозябры?

Comment: https://github.com/jeremyletang/rust-sfml/issues/310